# how to divide the input into two in single line

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I am getting one by one input fields, but I want to display as a single line, two input fields I want to show.

Now this my output:

```
Name
Password
```

Expected output:

```
Name password
```

Can any one help me

**updated html**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="login-input" placeholder=" Name" autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="login-input" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="text" name="father_name" class="login-input" placeholder=" Father Name" autofocus>
</div>

 <div>
     <input type="text" name="mother_name" class="login-input" placeholder=" Mother Name" autofocus>
     <textarea type="text" name="adress" class="login-input" placeholder=" Address" cols="40" rows="6" autofocus></textarea>
</div>
```

css:

```
 .login-input {
      display: inline-block
      width: 100%;
      height: 37px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 0 21px;
      color: white;
      text-shadow: 0 1px black;
      background: #2b3e5d;
      border: 1px solid #15243b;
      border-top-color: #0d1827;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
       box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block` and put every input fields you want to group together in separate `div`'s.

Comment: how to divide the equal space for input fields

Comment: You want to make them the same width ? Or add space between the two ?

Comment: No I gave the padding

Comment: see my updated post mother_name adress not coming in single line

Comment: You removed the html in your question

Comment: sorry now see my post

Comment: That's because `input` and `textarea` are different and `textarea` occupies more lines than `input`. Try `vertical-align: top /* or middle, depending on other fields */` on your textarea so it will align with the first line (where the `input` field is).